# Python : Find in an array of dict the element that match partially another dict

Tags: python

I have a dict `myDict` that look like this :

```
{
    'score': 1, 
    'surname': 'AA AA', 
    'name': 'AAA AAA'
}
```

And I have an array of dict `myArray` that look like this :

```
[
    {
        'score': 0.9, 
        'surname': 'AA AA', 
        'name': 'AAA AAA'
    },
    {
        'score': 0.6, 
        'surname': 'BB BB', 
        'name': 'BBB BBB'
    },
    ...
]
```

I am looking for a function that will find in `myArray`, the element that have the same `name` and `surname` that `myDict`, and return the `score`.

Is there a way to achieve this without manualy itering over `myArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, like this:

```
ls=[d for d in myArray if d["surname"]==myDict["surname"] and d["name"]==myDict["name"]]
```

This will give you a list of all dictionaries in `myArray` that match name and surname in `myDict`. If there will always only be one such value, you can retrieve the score with `ls[0]["score"]`.

Not though, that while list comprehensions are neat and compact Pythonic ways to do things, technically you are still iterating over `myArray`.

Otherwise you could consider converting `myArray` to a Pandas DataFrame and using it's built-in filtering functions.

Comment: if OP is certain that there will be at most one match, this code is rather wasteful because it does not stop after finding it. `next` would be the way to go.

Comment: True, but in reality the assumption that there are no duplicates usually doesn't hold and then you'll need to find all matches in any case. +1 for `next` though

Answer (score 2):

You can also just iterate through myArray with smth like this:

```
def find_score(myDict, myArray):
     name, surname = myDict['name'], myDict['surname']
     for i in myArray:
         if i['name'] == name and i['surname'] == surname:
             return i['score']
```

Comment: it could be more efficient if you stored the `myDict['name']` and `myDict['surname']` to avoid the lookup on every iteration. As a sidenote, you could take a look at `next`.